# pip packages in Spyder

Tags: python, pip, spyder

Pulling my hair out at this.

Just installed a `pip` package `pyodbc` but can't import it with Spyder.

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

However if I just try from Python via CMD I have no issues.

I've added `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages` (where the package was installed) to the PYTHONPATH manager in Spyder and restarted the kernal etc but to no avail.

[This](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) suggests I need to set up miniconda but surely I can do this with standalones?

Comment: check the output of `!where python` in spyder's ipython-console (with the ! ) ... you most probably have multiple pythons on your system

Comment: I have 2
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe`
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

Comment: and you're certain you've installed your package in the correct python env?  (`!pip show pyodbc` should tell you the installed version

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please follow [these instructions](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) instead and remove `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages` from our Python Path manager. That should allow you to import `pyodbc` in Spyder.

Comment: Yes! Thank you both. 

@CarlosCordoba Is there a way to link Spyder Projects to Virtual Environments so each time you swap between them it links to the right environment?

Comment: @Quixotic22, that's not possible at the moment, sorry. However, we're working to provide that functionality, so hopefully it'll be available next year.